# Play Framework 2: Is it possible to obtain custom annotation on Controller method from Http.Context?

Tags: playframework-2.0

**Background**
Using Java with Play Framework 2.3.
I want to send back a 404 from my overridden onUnauthorized method
of Security.Authenticator for AJAX calls. My plan is to add a custom 
annotation to the AJAX controller methods and respond accordingly (with 404)
from onUnauthorized.

**Issue**
I am in the onUnauthorized method and have access to Http.Context
which gives me the path requested. I not sure how I can get the annotation.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what exactly are you asking for, but seem slike you're looking for action compositions: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry if I was unclear. I was trying to determine if the requested path was trying to go to an AJAX method in the controller while in the unAuthorized method of Security.Authenticator. I was going to annotate the AJAX Controller methods to designate it was AJAX vs non-AJAX.